# I get the error message twice during validating a model attribute in rails

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Kindly, I am trying to validate the length of a model attribute in rails 5, but when I check the validation in the console, I receive the validation message twice. for ex. this is the validation code in the model:

```
validates_length_of :title, minimum: 2, maximum: 100
```

and when , I use the rails console, to create a new invalid record with nil title

```
message = Message.create(sender_id: 3)
```

and when I try to get the error message using: `message.errors.details`, I get

```
{:title=>[{:error=>:too_short, :count=>2}, {:error=>:too_short, :count=>2}]}
```

I noticed that issue during tests running using rspec. The test does not pass , rspec expects the error messages twice as displayed above.
any help please for what is causing this duplication in the error messages and how to avoid that.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for that, I spent so many times solving that issue, and I found some silly mistake which helped getting that error messages duplicated. sorry again